# Speed up applying function to a list of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have some time series data where each data point is a pandas data frame i.e. list of data frames. I also have a function `foo` which operates on each data point. The aim is to apply the function over the entire time series data and do it efficiently.

I have vectorized the function `foo` so that it operates on the entire data frame and achieved a speedup of around 32x.

The original code is as follows:

```py
def bar(row, cols):
    return tuple([row[col] for col in cols])

def foo(df, cols):
    keys = set()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        key = bar(row, cols)
        keys.add(key)

    # do calculations on keys that returns a numeric output, result
    return result # float64
```

The vectorized code is as follows:

```py
def vect_bar(df, cols):
    df['key'] = df[cols].values.sum(axis=1)
    return df

def vect_foo(df, cols):
    df['key'] = ""
    df = vect_bar(df, cols)
    keys = df.key.unique()

    # do calculations on keys that returns a numeric output, result
    return result # float64
```

The timing results are as follows:

```
%timeit -n 100 foo(df, cols)
100 loops, best of 3: 42.9 ms per loop

%timeit -n 100 vect_foo(df, cols)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.34 ms per loop
```

Note:
`cols` is a list of column names.
All the elements of the data frame are strings and of dtype object.

However, it still takes a long time to apply `vect_foo` to all the data points. How can I speed it up further?

I tried creating a pandas series from the data and using `series.apply()`. However, that did not cause any speedup from the regular for loop approach.

**EDIT**:
If I was not clear earlier, given a data frame, the function `vect_foo` is quite efficient. **What I want is a way to speed up applying `vect_foo` to all the data points i.e. the list of data frames.**

```py
data_series = pd.Series(data)
def apply_data():
    return data_series.apply(vect_foo, cols)
```

`data` is a list of pandas data frames i.e. `data = [df1, df2, ..., df50K]`

Here, I tried `pandas.Series.apply()` but it performed similarly to a normal for loop approach.

Comment: how big is the dataframe? also, am I to understand that you're basically just creating a new column called `keys` that sums up the values row wise?

Comment: Each data frame has rows in the range [50, 200]. The length of the list is around 50K. Yes, you are correct. I am adding the values row-wise, but only those columns specified by ```cols```.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

def foo(row, cols):
    row['keys'] = row[cols].sum()
    return row

df.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

just create your helper function and use the `apply` function. this is usually the most efficient way to apply a function across rows/columns in `pandas`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried ```apply``` like you suggested, however, ```vect_foo``` which operates on the entire data frame is around 4x faster. So I think the focus should be on applying ```vect_foo``` faster to all points in the list, not making ```vect_foo``` itself faster.

Comment: why does `vect_foo` exist? `vect_bar` should actually be more than enough if you want to apply it to the entire dataframe all at once.

Comment: You are correct. There are some other calculations in ```vect_foo``` that are not relevant to the question, so I removed them. You can consider only ```vect_bar```, it's just a convenience function, won't make a difference except for function call overhead, which is just once.

Comment: after you apply `vect_bar` to each dataframe in the list, do you plan on using `pandas.concat` on it?

Comment: No. ```vect_foo``` has some additional calculations on ```key``` that returns a numeric output. So, after applying ```vect_foo``` or ```vect_bar``` on each data frame in the list, I will get a list of numeric values that I want to plot.

Comment: honestly, if you still have to run efficiency markers for a function that already runs pretty efficiently, your best bet is to use `dask` and parallel process the computations.